# geopandas readfile not recognizing a legit shape file

Tags: geopandas, fiona

I am trying to read to geopandas what looks like a legitimate shapefile:

```
gpd.read_file('https://github.com/altcoder/philippines-psgc-shapefiles/blob/master/source/2015/Municities.zip')
```

However, I am getting a driver error:

```
DriverError: '/vsimem/dff0663a4e584987848e40266f6b73e8' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Searching unfortunately did not produce useful clues. I hope someone who knows geopandas or fiona could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When loading from GitHub, you need to pass a link to raw version of zip file. Otherwise, it links to GitHub page, not the file.

```py
gpd.read_file('https://github.com/altcoder/philippines-psgc-shapefiles/raw/master/source/2015/Municities.zip')
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a beginner like me. Learning everyday!